# Custom configuration for expanding bash expressions on TAB

Tags: linux, bash

I have a couple of commands that I use in bash quite frequently, e.g. one of them is `xbps-install <pkg-name>`. Autocompletion doesn't work well for such command, because there are a lot of another commands which starts with `xbps-*`. So I need to either write `xbps-inst<TAB>` for autocompletion or `xbps<10xTAB>` with looking for result. To avoid it I created aliases in `.bashrc`, like `xbi` for `xbps-install`. But I'd like to make it more explicit and avoid hiding command behind the aliases or links. Is it possible to create *something* (I don't really know what it could be in bash, maybe autocompletion?) to configure expression expanding by `TAB`: when I put `xbi<TAB>` convert it into `xbps-install`?

Comment: Anything like that would i) be _less_ explicit than simply having an alias and ii) would break expansion for everything else that might begin with `xbi`. Are you sure it's worth it?

Comment: @terdon maybe it's bossible to add `xbps-install` to completion list of `xbi<TAB>` expansion?

Comment: From my experience if you are tried with bash completion just install `zsh` or `fish` shell.